# Hibernate Mapping many-to-one with 'composite' table as joining

Tags: hibernate, join, mapping

please help me with this mapping issue (I'm using Hibernate 3.6).

I have these tables

```
CREATE  TABLE Towers (
  Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  Name VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id));

CREATE  TABLE LineOfBusiness (
  Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id));

CREATE  TABLE LineOfBusinessXTowers (
  LineOfBusinessId INT NOT NULL ,
  TowerId INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (LineOfBusinessId, TowerId));

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Departments (
  Code INT NOT NULL ,
  LineOfBusinessId INT NOT NULL ,
  TowerId INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (Code));

ALTER TABLE LineOfBusinessXTowers
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_LineOfBusinessXTowers_LineOfBusiness
    FOREIGN KEY (LineOfBusinessId)
    REFERENCES LineOfBusiness (Id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_LineOfBusinessXTowers_Towers
    FOREIGN KEY (TowerId)
    REFERENCES Towers (Id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE Departments
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Departments_LineOfBusinessXTowers
    FOREIGN KEY (LineOfBusinessId, TowerId)
    REFERENCES LineOfBusinessXTowers (LineOfBusinessId,TowerId)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

In the Hibernate mapping classes I'd like to have a Department class that have the correspondig Tower and LineOfBusiness objects:

```
public class Departments {
        private int code;
   private String name;
   private LineOfBusiness lineOfBusiness;
   private Towers tower;

       //Constructors and access methods here
}
```

I was trying to do the mapping this way, but is wrong:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="Departments" table="Departments" catalog="DB">
      <id name="code" type="int">
         <column name="Code" />
         <generator class="assigned" />
      </id>
      <property name="name" type="string">
         <column name="Name" length="45" not-null="true" unique="true" />
      </property>

      <join table="LineOfBusinessXTowers" optional="false">
         <key column="LineOfBusinessId" unique="false" />
         <many-to-one name="lineOfBusiness"
            class="LineOfBusiness">
            <column name="LineOfBusinessId" not-null="true" />
         </many-to-one>
      </join>
      <join table="LineOfBusinessXTowers" optional="false">
         <key column="TowerId" unique="false" />
         <many-to-one name="towers" class="Towers">
            <column name="TowerId" not-null="true" />
         </many-to-one>
      </join>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Which would be the correct mapping to do what I want to?
Can It be done?
Is there another better strategy?

Thank to you so much.

Atte:
Edgar

Comment: Is this a legacy database, or did you create it from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
<join table="LineOfBusinessXTowers" optional="false">
  <key column="LineOfBusinessId" unique="false" />
  <many-to-one name="lineOfBusiness" class="LineOfBusiness">
    <column name="LineOfBusinessId" not-null="true" />
  </many-to-one>
</join>
```

do

```
<many-to-one name="lineOfBusiness" class="LineOfBusiness">
  <column name="LineOfBusinessId" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
```

and the mapping to tower is not easily possible. Join does only support joining on the primaryKey/Id:

### Option 1: if lineOfBusiness has only ever 1 tower

```
// in department
public Towers getTower()
{
    return lineOfBusiness.getTower();
}

// in LineOfBusiness mapping
<join table="LineOfBusinessXTowers" optional="false">
  <key column="LineOfBusinessId" unique="false" />
  <many-to-one name="tower" column="TowerId" />
</join>
```

### Option 2: if lineOfBusiness has many tower

```
// in department
public Towers getTower()
{
    return lineOfBusiness.getTowers().getAt(0);
}

// in LineOfBusiness mapping
<set table="LineOfBusinessXTowers" optional="false">
  <key column="LineOfBusinessId" unique="false" />
  <many-to-many name="tower" column="TowerId" />
</join>
```

### Option 3: introduce an entity for the manytomany table

```
class LineOfBusinessAndTower
{
    private LineOfBusiness lineOfBusiness;
    private Tower tower;

    // override equality to take the two references into account
}

// in LineOfBusinessAndTower mapping
<Composite-id >
  <key-many-to-one name="lineOfBusiness" column="LineOfBusinessId" />
  <key-many-to-one name="tower" column="TowerId" />
</join>

// in Department mapping
<manytoone table="internalLineOfBusinessXTowers">
  <column="LineOfBusinessId" />
  <column="TowerId" />
</manytoone>

// in Department
public LineOfBusiness getLineOfBusiness()
{
    return internalLineOfBusinessXTowers.getLineOfBusiness();
}

public Towers getTower()
{
    return internalLineOfBusinessXTowers.getTower();
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I checked your solution but I think it applies to another DB design. I would like to maintain my current DB design because Tower and LineOfBusiness association is many-to-many (table LineOfBusinessXTowers) and that asociation is the one that has a one-to-many relation with Departments.

Comment: Option 2 handles it as a manytomany. you either need to change db or classmodel. i will add a third Option

Comment: I also thought in option 3 before, and even though is not what I wanted is a functional solution. As I'm new to hibernate I still don't get it completely how mapping works but I still thinks there is a way to do what I was trying to accomplish. 
Thank you very much.